# Why was the Dragon's Tooth enough to bring peace to the Triads?

Tags: video-games, deus-ex

In DeusEx, the Triads fight with all tricks against each other. When J.C. retrieves the Dragon's Tooth from Maggie Chow, suddenly the leaders of the Luminous Path and the Red Arrow become best friends and invite J.C. for a drink. The Dragon's Tooth is vastly helpful for J.C. in particular, but not *that* a devastating weapon in general, that the atom-bomb effect ("war implies mutual annihilation") would apply.

So, why would that cause such a sudden peace between these old rivals?

Comment: It has been a while since playing, but Chow was probably tricking both Triads. By taking her achievement and giving it to the tricked parties, their conflict was likely removed and they had no reason to continue to fight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this:](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon%27s_Tooth_sword_%28DX%29)

A prototype of the dragon's tooth is actually what started the fight between the triads. It's further explained that Maggie Chow had been manipulating the conflict between the triads to keep the conflict going and keeping the two sides from working together.

Once Maggie Chow's true intentions are revealed and the sword is given to both sides, there is no further reason for the triads to fight amongst themselves. If anything they now have a common enemy in VersaLife.